Pytest/FastAPI asyncio tests run individually but fail when run as a group
I have a set of pytest tests that when run individually pass, but when run as a group fail. I am using an in-memory SQLite database, which is set up and torn down in async fixtures with the scope set to "function". I have annotated the code and have seen this occurring. When the tests are run as a group it appears as if the database tables are created but the contents of the database are not added.
The code below is the top half of the test file. test_team_endpoint ansd test_Active_team_endpoint both pass when run as
poetry run pytest team_test.py::test_team_endpoint
poetry run pytest team_test.py::test_active_team_endpoint
but when run as
poetry run pytest team_test.py
then test_team_endpoint passes but test_active_team_endpoint fails with a 404 as no teams had been found in the database.
import pytest
import pytest_asyncio
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient
from backend.db.models.club_model import Club
from backend.db.models.team_model import Team
from loguru import logger
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import AsyncSession, create_async_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.pool import StaticPool

from internaladminserver.application import get_app
from internaladminserver.model.dependencies import get_db_session
from internaladminserver.tests import database1
from internaladminserver.tests.database1 import club_data, team_data
from internaladminserver.tests.team.expected_results import (
    test_active_team_endpoint_result, test_invalid_id_result,
    test_team_endpoint_by_id_result,
    test_team_endpoint_by_id_result_updated_club_id, test_team_endpoint_result,
    test_unknown_id_result)

# Use an asynchronous in-memory SQLite database with StaticPool and session
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = "sqlite+aiosqlite:///:memory:"

engine = create_async_engine(
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL,
    connect_args={"check_same_thread": False},
    poolclass=StaticPool,
)


AsyncSessionFactory = sessionmaker(
    bind=engine, class_=AsyncSession, expire_on_commit=True
)


@pytest_asyncio.fixture(scope="function")
async def populate_db():
    """
    Populate the database with test data.
    """
    async with engine.begin() as conn:
        await conn.run_sync(lambda conn: Team.__table__.create(conn))
        await conn.run_sync(lambda conn: Club.__table__.create(conn))

    async with AsyncSessionFactory() as session:
        try:
            session.add_all(club_data)
            session.add_all(team_data)
            await session.commit()
            await session.begin()
            yield session
        finally:
            await session.close()

    async with engine.begin() as conn:
        await conn.run_sync(lambda conn: Club.__table__.drop(conn))
        await conn.run_sync(lambda conn: Team.__table__.drop(conn))


@pytest_asyncio.fixture(scope="function")
async def create_client(populate_db):
    """
    Create a new FastAPI test client for a test.
    """
    async def override_get_db():
        async with populate_db as session:
            yield session

    app = get_app()
    app.dependency_overrides[get_db_session] = override_get_db

    with TestClient(app) as client:
        yield client


@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_team_endpoint(create_client):
    response = create_client.get("/api/team")
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert response.json() == test_team_endpoint_result


@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_active_team_endpoint(create_client):
    response = create_client.get("/api/team?status=active")
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert response.json() == test_active_team_endpoint_result



I have annotated the code and can see that the database and session are torn down and recreated each time. I have checked the session functions and confirmed that the ones that need awaiting are awaited. I have naturally searched stackoverflow, asked ChatGPT and other sources of information.
my pytest.ini
[pytest]
filterwarnings =
    ignore::DeprecationWarning
    ignore::PendingDeprecationWarning
    ignore::UserWarning
asyncio_mode = auto



This question would be easier to answer if it included an [mcve] -- code that we can run to reproduce the problem. Narrow it down to a single file that only depends on pytest and sqlalchemy, that includes both the code under test and the tests. If we can run it and reproduce the problem locally we're in a much better position to see what's causing the problem.
